# Characters of alternating groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, characters

I am studying certain properties of characters of alternating groups and I have found precisely three characters not satisfying it up to $A_{15}$. These are:

1. A character of dimension $3.696$ of $A_{12}$. As $S_{12}$ has no character of dimension $2 \cdot 3.696 = 7.392$, it must correspond to the restriction of a character of $S_{12}$. There are precisely two characters of this dimension with partitions $(5,2,2,1,1,1)$ and $(6,3, 1,1,1)$ (transpose of each other).
2. A character of dimension $6.864$ of $A_{13}$. As $S_{13}$ has no character of dimension $2 \cdot 6.864 = 13.728$, it must correspond to the restriction of a character of $S_{13}$. There are precisely two characters of this dimension with partitions $(4,2,2,2,1,1,1)$ and $(7,4,1,1)$ (transpose of each other).
3. A character of dimension $32.032$ of $A_{15}$. As $S_{15}$ has no character of dimension $2 \cdot 32.032 = 64.064$, it must correspond to the restriction of a character of $S_{15}$. There are precisely two characters of this dimension with partitions $(3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1)$ and $(8,5,2)$ (transpose of each other).

Is there anything special about these characters of the alternating/symmetric group?